# Как найти HTML код в админ. панели Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla, cms

Привет, Мир!

Ребята, у меня возникла такая проблема, мне необходимо поменять `html` код в `Joomla`, т.к. блоки были помещены в теги `<tr>` и `<td>`, что является не лучшим вариантом для адаптивной верстки, теперь я скачал архив через файловый менеджер и через поиск в `Notepad++` поискал во всех файлах и папках, но ничего не нашел.

Теперь возникает вопрос как его найти через админ.панель? Однако, я искал и заходил в шаблон, но безуспешно.

Пожалуйста помогите, может быть есть быстрый способ? Или установка отдельного `модуля` и `плагина`?

Comment: Joomla, кажись, в базе все держит. Там и ищите

Comment: @splash58 значит с базы надо редактировать?

Comment: я ей не пользуюсь, не могу сказать наверняка, но очень на то похоже :)

Answer (score 0):

> Или установка отдельного модуля и  плагина?

`Joomla framework`  - это не движок `Wordpress`, `Joomla!` более серьёзна в плане работы с кодом.
Для того чтобы редактировать код в шаблоне, вам надо зайти в 
`root\templates\vash_shablon\index.php` 
основная часть сайта (вёрстки)  находится в нём. Однако многое зависит от того что вы хотите изменить, т.к `Joomla` является `MVC` фреймворком, то некоторые 'куски кода' могут подключаться из `view` какого-то компонента или модуля. Вы можете для начала посмотреть в `index.php`, если не найдёте нужное строение `HTML`, напишите в комментах что вы хотите поменять (для какой страницы).